# gradle how to avoid latest version being pulled from artifactory

Tags: gradle

My gradle dependency tree shows as below

```
+--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:3.6.2 -> 4.5.1
```

Since there are few changes in 4.5.1 which are not backward compatible , I want to force version 3.6.2 to be picked up.

how to stop gradle from pulling the latest version from the artifactory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradle's resolution strategy to override declared dependency versions:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:3.6.2'
  }
}
```

[Further Reading](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)